# Is there any way to rename the section name in a .o or .a file compiled by gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, object-files

I have a precompiled library compiled with a gcc-based compiler and I would like to move the functions from the default `.text` section to some other section name (let's say `foo`). Is there a way to do this using binutils without recompiling?

Comment: Edit the linker script.

Comment: ? That has no bearing on this question; the linker doesn't affect this library at all, it's just the compiler and the `ar` utility.

Comment: TRhe linker is responsible to link the final program code. Ant that's where you can mpa the sections from each input file to the output's sections resp. segments. So yes, it very well is involved. You are just looking at the wrong place. What do you expect will happen with an unknow section from an input file when you eventually link it?

Comment: You can use [`objcopy --rename-section`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objcopy.1.html), for example.

Comment: @Olaf "What do you expect will happen with an unknow section from an input file when you eventually link it?" -- our linker script places sections that don't otherwise match, into the `.text` output section, so it doesn't change how things are linked. I'm just trying to partition program object code from this particular library into a contiguous area.

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea. You normally discard such sections not to clutter the binary with unexpected stuff. What do you mean with "continous area"? The same section of a module is normally not split by the linker.

Comment: @NominalAnimal -- thanks! Post as an answer and I'll accept. This worked great for me and I was able to see more clearly how much program and data memory was used by a particular library.

Answer (score 3):

.a library or static library is nothing but collection of object files only.

So before linking you can use objcpy rename command to change name of your sections.
Similarly you can change symbol name also using " -redefine-sym"

> --rename-section oldname=newname[,flags]
> Rename a section from oldname to newname, optionally changing the
> section's flags to flags in the process.  This has the advantage
> over using a linker script to perform the rename in that the
> output stays as an object file and does not become a linked
> executable.

#### Usage:

```
objcopy -I binary -O <output_format> -B <architecture>
    --rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents
    <input_binary_file> <output_object_file>
```

Refer: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objcopy.1.html

Answer (score 1):

### Linker Script

You can also us `ld` to rename sections using a linker script.

`ld -r -T section_rename.xsc -o output.o input.o`

Where the `section_rename.xsc` might look  similar to the following:

```
SECTIONS
{
  .newtext : { *(.text) }
  .newdata : { *(.data) }
}
```